# PowerApps - Listbox - Update selected values into SP list

Tags: listbox, powerapps

I have some problems with a couple of listboxes in a powerapps app. There is an app with 4-5 pages and forms for collecting info. Most works fine but I cant get the selected info in the listbox to work. Im guessing its simple but.. please help.

`Update = Listbox.SelectedItems` - I want something like this.. but either Im only getting one selected value or error message.. Tried some different like Text() - SelectedItemsText osv osv.. cant fint the right one I guess.

Thnx.

Comment: What is the type of the corresponding column in your SharePoint list? And what is the expression that you are using for the Items property of your listbox?

Comment: Its a textfield - tried single and multiline - and I get the items from a seperate list so the expression is just items=SP_list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally seems to have found what I was looking for..

```
Left(Concat(DataCardValue3.SelectedItemsText.Value; Concatenate(Text(Value); ", ")); Len(Concat(DataCardValue3.SelectedItemsText.Value; Concatenate(Text(Value); ""))) - 1)
```

**Thnx!**